# How can I encode None to missing json field using zio-json instead of null?

Tags: scala, zio, zio-json

Let's say I have a case class with the optional field `nickName` and codec like this:

```
final case class Person(name: String, nickName: Option[String])

object Person {
  implicit val personCodec: JsonCodec[Person] = DeriveJsonCodec.gen
}
```

I want to encode it using `zio-json (v1.5.0)` and have this as result:

```
{"name":"SomeName"}
```

And this is my test for it:

```
encoder.encodeJson(Person("SomeName", None), None).toString shouldBe """{"name":"SomeName"}""".stripMargin
```

Looks like the `zio-json` encode `None` with `null` and I've get the test error:

```
Expected :"{"name":"SomeName"[]}"
Actual   :"{"name":"SomeName"[,"nickName":null]}"
```

I checked the code and found the encoder for Option https://github.com/zio/zio-json/blob/52d007ee22f214d12e1706b016f149c3243c632c/zio-json/shared/src/main/scala/zio/json/encoder.scala#L188-L202

Any idea how I can encode it as a missing JSON field?

Comment: It works as expected with zio-json 0.2.0-M3. Also, the latest milestone have a lot of performance improvements for serialization.

Answer (score 2):

```
implicit val OptionStringCodec: JsonCodec[Option[String]] = JsonCodec.string.xmap( s =>
    s match {
      case null | "" => None
      case s         => Some(s)
    },
    _.getOrElse("")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm not familiar sith zio-json, there might be another way like a configuration to achieve the same thing.*

Given the sample of code you linked, you can easily write an encoder that doesn't write anything in case of none by copying most of the code but modifying:

```scala
def unsafeEncode(oa: Option[A], indent: Option[Int], out: Write): Unit = oa match {
  case None    => () // out.write("null")
  case Some(a) => A.unsafeEncode(a, indent, out)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't find the way to let `zio-json` use the custom encoder